# Shape key for muscular/fitness of a model?

Tags: shape-keys

I have been wondering for a while if it would be possible to sort of interpolate between a model's "fitness" while still taking into account it's "weight".

For example, say you have a `weight` shape key which increases the width of the model, but you also have a `fitness` shape key which "tones" or makes the muscles more defined on the model. You could then have a model which could be slim and toned, obese, anemic, or strong; and everything in between.

IIRC there are humanoid model creation tools that do this to create a finalized mesh, but are there any that can also export the shape keys with the model?

I would gladly try to do it myself but I don't know where to start. Creating a "weight" shape key is easy, but how and even if it is possible to blend it with the "fitness" shape key is something I do not know.

For some reason I feel like it is much more difficult than I think, to accomplish something like this (especially since a lot of the tools take years to develop). A few immediate challenges I can think of with this (if it is even possible) is:

1. Modifying the textures may be an essential part to making the model looked "toned", or maybe as an alternative or if it is needed additionally, a "higher than normal" resolution model may be needed.
2. It may be difficult to create such a large variety of shapes on the same mesh and vertex count (IIRC shape keys only work if vertex count doesn't change).

In case you haven't guessed it already, my main goal with this would be to have a dynamic character range in a game, so exporting the shape keys is the only way I can think of doing this, besides maybe exporting multiple models for the same character.

**I.E.**

1. One model which includes the shape key for the "heavy" range, like "obese" to "heavy wieght lifter"
2. Another model that covers the "light" range, like "weak anemic" to "marathon runner".
3. You would then have models in between these two, to cover the gaps.

But this method seems way too wasteful, I would ideally just interpolate between the two of them, or have a single mesh with all the shape keys.

If there is other methods please let me know, if it is a difficult task then I may have to forget about this altogether. Thank you all in advanced for the help!

Comment: I should also say I have very limited experience modeling/designing, so some of my assumptions may be way off.

Comment: For these kind of things it helps to thing of things as a grid, with one axis being weight and the other being fitness. If you have a single model and make shapekeys for each extreme e.g. [heavy,unfit],[heavy,fit] etc as one shape, and blend between them based on something like distance on the 'grid'.

Comment: @Sazerac So instead of having two shape keys (one shape key for weight, and one for fitness), I should have four (as you said one for each extreme). I think this will work quite well actually, thanks for the tip :)